# Leaflet.js : Add custom text to layers control using CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I am building an interactive map using Leaflet.js. The out-of-the-box layers panel that comes with Leaflet is difficult to hack. My users have large resolution monitors and they easily miss this little collapsed layers icon. So, what I want to do is add the text "View Overlays" to the right of the icon. Apparently, the icon is also larger than what is shown in the map. It looks like CSS is shrinking it down a little, but I am not sure how to revert the icon size back to its default larger size.

[image]

Here's my attempt to get started, but it's not very good ([plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/S03q3WhldwVh5VswcS9S?p=preview))

```
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
  width: 200px;
}
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle:after {
  content: 'View Overlays';
  padding-left: 2em; 
}
```

Questions:

**1.) How do I increase size of that sandwich icon?**

**2.) How do I correctly add the text "View Overlays" and keep the element from going into an epileptic seizure?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.) How do I increase size of that sandwich icon?

The sandwich icon is a background image. This background image is made out of multiple images, see the full image [here](http://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.4/images/icons-000000@2x.png). It is resized and placed to fit with Leaflet's CSS definition here:

```
.leaflet-container.dark .map-tooltip .close, .leaflet-control-attribution::after, .leaflet-control-layers-toggle, .leaflet-control-zoom-in, .leaflet-control-zoom-out, .leaflet-popup-close-button, .map-tooltip .close, .mapbox-icon {
    opacity: 0.75;
    background-image: url("images/icons-000000@2x.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 26px 260px;
}
```

You have to change several CSS definitions to get it working right, it would probably be easier to cut the image with an image editor and make it the right size...

Changing background size and position:

```
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
  background-size: 56px 560px;
}

.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
  background-position: 0px -235px;
}
```

You might also want to resize the `a` height and line-height and left margin, since it doesn't care about the background size and would either cut off the background or the text run into the icon.

```
.leaflet-container a {
  width: auto;
  height: 3em;
}

.leaflet-container a:after {
  margin-left: 30px;
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

> 2.) How do I correctly add the text "View Overlays" and keep the element from going into an epileptic seizure?

Problem is that your active and inactive box have different size, make them the same width and it should work:

```
.leaflet-control-layers {
  width: 200px;
}
```

See code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/2Vkci7MtfGcm9tvCUblx?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. It needs to be 600px wide but doesn't look good when it's collapsed at that width. But, you gave me a foundation to start with. Thanks again.